# Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

With reference to this [WebView](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html) tutorial, in particular this method

```
private void setupWebView(){
    String MAP_URL = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html";
    String centerURL = "javascript:centerAt(" + mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + ","+ mostRecentLocation.getLongitude()+ ")";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //Wait for the page to load then send the location information
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            webView.loadUrl(centerURL);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);
}
```

I've noticed that if I place the `webView.loadUrl(centerURL);` directly after
`webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);` like this

```
private void setupWebView(){
    String MAP_URL = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html";
    String centerURL = "javascript:centerAt(" + mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mostRecentLocation.getLongitude()+ ")";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //Wait for the page to load then send the location information
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            //DO NOTHING
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);
    webView.loadUrl(centerURL);
}
```

it no longer works. So the `centreAt(..)` javascript method is contained int the `MAP_URL`.

I'm wondering if the `webView.loadUrl(..)` method returns before the url has actually been loaded.
It looks that way since the top method waits for it to load fully before running the javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `webView.loadUrl()` is asynchronous: it returns immediately and WebView keeps working in it's own thread.

To monitor WebView page loading use [`WebViewClient.onPageFinished(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: Groan.... I just wasted the whole day to discover that. Oh well. Cheers for confirming Peter.