# Loading in WebView

Tags: android, webview, loading

I need to make a loading bar before opening the address in the WebView. It is blank and can not do with topics found here.  You need to load before opening.

Sorry for my English.

```
public class TelaPrincipal extends ActionBarActivity{

WebView webView;
private static final String TAG = TelaPrincipal.class.getSimpleName();
private String mCM;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
private final static int FCR=1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        Uri[] results = null;
        //Check if response is positive
        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUMA){
                    return;
                }
                if(intent == null){
                    //Capture Photo if no image available
                    if(mCM != null){
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                }else{
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if(dataString != null){
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
    }else{
        if(requestCode == FCR){
            if(null == mUM) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUM = null;
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.telaprincipal);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    assert webView != null;
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    webView.loadUrl("https://strikebrasil.gmpe.com.br/login");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        //For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            TelaPrincipal.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FCR);
        }

        // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            TelaPrincipal.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FCR);
        }
        //For Android 4.1+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            TelaPrincipal.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), TelaPrincipal.FCR);
        }
        //For Android 5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
            if(mUMA != null){
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(TelaPrincipal.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                File photoFile = null;
                try{
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if(photoFile != null){
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                }else{
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if(takePictureIntent != null){
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            }else{
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

// Create an image file
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webView.canGoBack()){
                    webView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

I have a splash before ... but what I do not get all white if the page has not yet been charged. I want to show a shipment and then only when you are 100% loaded, display the page.
Thanks

Comment: Hope this would help: [Show ProgressDialog until WebView finishes loading the WebPage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33444421/6213557).

Answer (score 0):

Put your webview inside framelayout and putan imageview also in framelayout. While page is loading show the imageView(animate if you want).