# Webview sometime seems like white or transparent when I load the pdf url

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Webview sometime seems like white or transparent when I load the pdf URL with appending "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=", Please help me out on this.

`webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$fileUrl")`

Comment: please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241584/8040930

Comment: tried, it's not working

Comment: paste the xml layout and the class file as well

Comment: where is XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Set Hardware Accelerated true in manifest

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

this worked for me. hopefully this will also help someone.