# android WebView flashing white when URL changes

Tags: android, webview

I have loaded local html structure inside a **WebView**. When I click on `<a>` link to go to another local html file, the webview goes white for some miliseconds and then renders the next page. I have read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476151/webview-flashing-with-white-background-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled-an) but it is just about then background color. I have no background color but it is visible that there is no element at first and then content is loaded after a few miliseocnds. How can I avoid such effect in my app?

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852123/5491571 
don't forget to share feedback

Comment: I have tested the above solution but no change @AbubakarCH